# Retaining values after generating data source for each key in map

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a variable `cloudwatch_log_prefixes` which is a map containing a list of cloudwatch log group prefixes and a filter for each prefix. Using this, I'm able to generate a data source which is a list of all the cloudwatch log groups from the given prefixes.

However I'm struggling to find out how to retain those filter values in the prefix map, as I'd like to use them as filters for each of the cloudwatch log group.

Current configuration:

```
variable "cloudwatch_log_prefixes" {
  default = {
    "/aws/lambda/type1_" = {"filter"},
    "/aws/lambda/type2_"    = {"*"},
  }
}

data "aws_cloudwatch_log_groups" "cloudwatch_groups" {
  for_each              = var.cloudwatch_log_prefixes
  log_group_name_prefix = each.key
}

locals {
  log_groups = {
    for log_group in flatten([for log_group in data.aws_cloudwatch_log_groups.cloudwatch_groups : log_group.log_group_names]) :
    log_group => {}
  }
}

output "log_groups" {
  value = local.log_groups
}
```

Current output

```
log_groups = {
    "/aws/lambda/type1/func1" = {},
    "/aws/lambda/type1/func2" = {},
    "/aws/lambda/type2/func1" = {},
    "/aws/lambda/type2/func2" = {},
}
```

Desired output

```
log_groups = {
    "/aws/lambda/type1/func1" = {"filter"},
    "/aws/lambda/type1/func2" = {"filter"},
    "/aws/lambda/type2/func1" = {"*"},
    "/aws/lambda/type2/func2" = {"*"},
}
```

Additional information

```bash
> tf state show 'data.aws_cloudwatch_log_groups.cloudwatch_groups["/aws/lambda/type1_"]'
# data.aws_cloudwatch_log_groups.cloudwatch_groups["/aws/lambda/type1_"]:
data "aws_cloudwatch_log_groups" "cloudwatch_groups" {
    arns                  = [
        "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:111111111:log-group:/aws/lambda/type1_func1",
        "arn:aws:logs:eu-central-1:111111111:log-group:/aws/lambda/type1_func2",
    ]
    id                    = "eu-central-1"
    log_group_name_prefix = "/aws/lambda/type1_"
    log_group_names       = [
        "/aws/lambda/type1_func1",
        "/aws/lambda/type1_func2",
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is actually the output that data source provides? Can you add that to the question?

Comment: @MarkoE this is the data source: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudwatch_log_groups (I understand my question might not be in a minimal reproducible way, I'm trying to find out how to print the data source, or like the first key, value in it !)

Comment: I know what the data source is. I need to see how its output looks like to be able to comment/answer.

Comment: Yes, I got that. I just didn't know how to actually retrieve the data source, which was what I tried to explain above haha. I've edited my question and added output of `tf state show` now. Just realised this was the wrong data source, I'm still trying...

Comment: Ha, no worries, I misunderstood you. :) Btw, the output seems to be a singular (i.e., `aws_cloudwatch_log_group`) but your question says `aws_cloudwatch_log_groups`. Which one of the two are you using? :)

Comment: My bad once again :p I realised I had added the incorrect data source as soon as I edited my question, `aws_cloudwatch_log_group` is used internally within the datadog module which I'm referencing in my tf configuration files. I'm only using `aws_cloudwatch_log_groups`, sorry about the confusion :) Edited question with correct data source !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the input information from the data source, I think something like this should work:

```
locals {
  log_groups = merge(flatten([
    for k, v in data.aws_cloudwatch_log_groups.cloudwatch_groups : {
      for i in v.log_group_names : 
        i => var.cloudwatch_log_prefixes[v.log_group_name_prefix]
    }
  ])...)
}

output "log_groups" {
  value = local.log_groups
}
```

This uses a combination of [`merge`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/merge) and [`flatten`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/flatten#flattening-nested-structures-for-for_each) built-in functions and the [ellipsis operator](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/function-calls#expanding-function-arguments) (`...`) to create a single map.

As a side note, you cannot assign values that start with `{` and end with `}` (`{"filter"}` and `{"*"}`) as terraform will render it invalid because it will take it for a start of a `map` type which expects a key value pair, i.e:

> Missing key/value separator: Expected an equals sign ("=") to mark the beginning of the attribute value.

Comment: Your answer as such worked perfectly for me ! I made some super small changes as the interpolation operator is apparently getting deprecated soon. Thanks a lot !

I do have one more question. How do you go about replicating such manipulation tasks locally? Do you just create temporary variables for inputs and outputs, or do you use a CLI or such? Sorry if the question is quite vague :)

Comment: Good to hear it worked. :) Well, based on the data output I try to reconstruct the values as a local variable and then I can do almost everything the same as if I had the data source returning the values. After that, I usually check the outputs by using the `terraform console`. :) I hope that is the answer to your question. Btw, which operator is getting deprecated? 

Comment: That answers my question. `terraform console` looks useful ! And my linter showed that the interpolation operator is deprecated, it should be this: https://github.com/terraform-linters/tflint-ruleset-terraform/blob/v0.2.2/docs/rules/terraform_deprecated_interpolation.md (Here's the edited tf block: https://codefile.io/f/IPeJEHx8JG)

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work with changed interpolation, terraform does not complain, but I'm getting now this output: `{"i" = "{*}"}`. Without the interpolation, it is treating `i` as a key and not an element of the `v.log_group_names` array. Furthermore, since all the keys are the same, it merges it into the last one, i.e., instead of having four, it just takes the last one.

Comment: I did get the same error, but resolved it changing the grouping/brackets and such. Could you try out this minimal reproducible solution? https://codefile.io/f/tx9Algo7kL

Comment: Yup, that works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255673/discussion-between-suraj-and-marko-e).